# Erro de sintaxe no WHERE do SELECT usando parâmetros do ADO.Net

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Alguém compreende este erro e consegue uma solução?

[image: ERRO DE SINTAXE]

Código:

```
OleDbConnection ConSelect = new OleDbConnection();
ConSelect.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.dbInvoice;

ConSelect.Open();
OleDbCommand CmmSelect = new OleDbCommand();

CmmSelect.CommandText = "SELECT Qtd, UnitPriceInv FROM JAN WHERE EmgPartInv = ? AND CodCliInv = ? AND InvoiceName = ? ";
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@EmgPart", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtEmg.Text;
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@CodCli", OleDbType.Integer, 18).Value = txtCodCli.Text;
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", OleDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = label45.Text;

CmmSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
CmmSelect.Connection = ConSelect;
OleDbDataReader DRSelectCond;
DRSelectCond = CmmSelect.ExecuteReader();
DRSelectCond.Read();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece simples, substitua as virgulas por `AND`:

```
"... EmgPartInv = ? AND CondCliInv=? AND InvoiceName = ?"
```

Seguinte quanto à "No value given for one or more required parameters." Está falando que não há valor pro parâmetro, mude sua *query* para:

```
CmmSelect.CommandText = "SELECT Qtd, UnitPriceInv FROM JAN WHERE EmgPartInv = @EmgPart AND CodCliInv = @CodCli AND InvoiceName = @Invoice ";
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@EmgPart", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtEmg.Text;
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@CodCli", OleDbType.Integer, 18).Value = txtCodCli.Text;
CmmSelect.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", OleDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = label45.Text;
```

Comment: Teve progresso, mas o erro mudou para:
`Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.`

Comment: E então, quando em último caso, coloco os valores de resultados direto na Sintaxe.. o erro também é outro:

`Additional information: Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta 'EmgPartInv = bt 234 AND CodCliInv = 1 AND InvoiceName = INV123'.`

Comment: @MaurícioSanches Que raios é "bt 234"? - Sugeriria testar a query separado direto no DB, e depois aplicar no código, senão fica difícil.

Comment: Com a edição que o, a sintaxe deu certo. e com a recomendação do @Bacco eu descobri um erro na sintaxe usando a Query direto no DB. o parametro QTD na verdade deveria ser QTDInv. 

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Isso deixará correto:

```
"SELECT Qtd, UnitPriceInv FROM JAN WHERE EmgPartInv = @EmgPart AND CodCliInv = @CodCli AND InvoiceName = @Invoice"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CSharp.sql).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandText).